# 'the' or 'a' to indicate a specific data type (CS context)

Tags: articles, expressions, idiomatic-language

I googled myself a little to see which article is more commonly used with types, and I understood one commonly uses **a** to indicate a general type such as `integer`.

But what about *a specific type* such as a structure? For example, which one should I use when I'm writing a sentence like below?

> A: Assume a delegate pointer is **a** *T* type.
>
> B: Assume a delegate pointer is **the** *T* type.

I used *T* to denote the name of a specific data type. Both look somewhat awkward for me, since A is like it's indicating one of many *T* types (which is not), and B looks a little redundant due to **the**.

Some might suggest I can simply write

> Assume a delegate pointer is *T*,

but I'd rather make it clear that the *T* I'm using is a kind of type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I'd say is

> Assume a delegate pointer is **of type** T.

In casual conversation, I might say any of the following:

> Assume a delegate pointer is a T.
>
> Assume a delegate pointer has a type of T. (best)
>
> Assume a delegate pointer has the type T.
>
> Assume a delegate pointer has type T.

but these all sound less CS-like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I also wondered if I can say 'type T' without an article. :]